# Wordpress WooCommerce Menu Extension Big search button removal

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, menu

is there a way to remove big orange search button at menu at top without going into files? Website :https://www.pacopac.eu/

Need search but withuat that big ugly button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to wp-admin -> Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS 
and add this CSS

```
ul.menu-pagrindinis li input[type="submit"] {
    display: none;
}
```